# How can I simplify the output of the Reduce to a more compact form?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, output-formatting

Below is the code.

```
Reduce[(a + b - c) (a - b + c) (-a + b + c) (a + b + c) >= 0 && 0 < a <= 1 && 0 < b <= 1 && 0 < c <= 1, {a, b, c}]
```

This does generate the constraints on $a,b$ and $c$ but can it be simplified further to a readable form?

Any help  would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you imagine a simplification of `(0 < a < 1/
    2 && ((a + b >= 
        c && ((a == b && a < b + c) || (0 < b < a && 
           a <= b + c) || (a + c >= b && a < b && 
           a + b <= 1))) || (a + c >= b && b <= 1 && a + b > 1 && 
       c <= 1))) || (1/2 <= a < 
    1 && ((c <= 
        1 && ((a == b && 0 < c) || (a + c >= b && a < b && 
           b <= 1) || (a > b && a + b >= 1 && a <= b + c))) || (a + 
         b < 1 && a + b >= c && a <= b + c && b > 0))) || (a == 1 && 
   c <= 1 && ((b == 1 && 0 < c) || (b + c >= 1 && 0 < b && b < 1)))`?

Comment: The original argument to `Reduce` is a more compact form. Asking to solve for `{a, b, c}` is what causes the expanded form. If you want to visualize the expression use `RegionPlot3D[(a + b - c) (a - b + c) (-a + b + c) (a + b + c) >= 0 && 
  0 < a <= 1 && 0 < b <= 1 && 0 < c <= 1, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0,
   1},
 PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 5]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks for the help.

Comment: BTW, Maple 2021 produces the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us make

```
 Reduce[(a + b - c) (a - b + c) (-a + b + c) (a + b + c) >= 0 && {a, b, c} > 0, {a, b, c}]
```

> `a > 0 && ((0 < b < a && a - b <= c <= a + b) || (b == a &&  a - b < c <= a + b) || (b > a && -a + b <= c <= a + b))`

and then add `{a,b,c} <= 1`:

```
a > 0 && ((0 < b < a && a - b <= c <= a + b) || (b == a && 
 a - b < c <= a + b) || (b > a && -a + b <= c <= a + b)) && {a,b,c} <= 1
```

This is a simpler expression than the result of your code, but equivalent to it as

```
Resolve[ForAll[{a, b, c}, Equivalent[  a > 0 && ((0 < b < a && a - b <= c <= a + b) || (b == a && 
a - b < c <= a + b) || (b > a && -a + b <= c <= a + b)) && {a,
b, c} <= 1, (a + b - c) (a - b + c) (-a + b + c) (a + b + c) >=
0 && {a, b, c} > 0 && {a, b, c} <= 1]], Reals]
```

> `True`

shows.